# Flutter model_viewer plugin for iOS not showing anything

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality, arcore, virtual-reality

I tried to build an AR app using Flutter and model_viewer plugin. It works just fine in Android but when I tried to test it using iOS it is just showing a blank page. I tried to follow the documentation provided in https://pub.dev/packages/model_viewer by adding :

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<true/>
```

but nothing has changed.  Can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to insert YES instead of true, beetwen a balise string like?

io.flutter.embedded_views_preview
YES